Is there any standard container format for single file encryption with metadata and random read access support?
Is there a standard for single-file encryption container, that:

allows random read access of encrypted file contents (is seekable for reading),
stores public metadata (not-encrypted, but can be signed if desired),
stores private metadata,
has multi-recipient support (password(s), public key cryptography).

I know how to invent own standard by gluing multiple blobs, using NaCL library and JWE for metadata with multiple recipients support.
However, I would like to reuse an existing standard if any such exists, rather than inventing another one.

CMS (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652) is a large standard that probably "supports" all the features you want in the sense that it is very general. However, it's not for everybody, and you may find that a custom solution is still preferable.
